# Are mongodb connections synchronous?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose we had a scenario like this....

```
Thread.start {
   db.collection.find({})
}

Thread.start {
   db.collection.find({})
}
```

If i am using the same database connection for both threads, is it possible for this to execute both queries at the same time? Or would i need a completely seperate connection to the database. I plan on making an express api and I am curious if I hit the api with 1000 requests if it would be able to query the database concurrently with only 1 database connection.

Comment: The db queries can be both called in order without blocking but you need to add your callback to your function if you want the results.

Comment: @exceptionsAreBad my question wasnt whether or not it would work, but if it would work concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB uses locking and concurrency control to prevent clients from modifying the same data simultaneously. [MongoDB Concurrency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/)